# Audio noise when transmitting radio packets using the ESP32

Tags: capacitor, rf, voltage-regulator, noise, esp32

I am building a sort of walkie-talkie using an ESP32 WROOM chip. I use the internal ADC to sample the microphone and the internal DAC to power small headphones. This all works OK, not the highest quality, but sufficient.

**The problem**

I send the audio data over 2.4 GHz (using the ESP-NOW protocol.) The problem is that I am experiencing noise on the receiving side, with the same frequency as transmitting the packet. For example, I am transmitting each 20 ms sound audio packet 6 times, given that there are 50 frames of 20 ms in a second, that gives 50 * 6 = 300 transmissions per second, then a 300 Hz tone can be heard at the receiver, next to other audio like speech.

**The (suspected) cause**

I suspect this is due to voltage drops I see on the 3.3 V supply line. I used a 600 mA [RT9080 LDO](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2183318.pdf), which should more than sufficient for the radio.
Using an oscilloscope, I can see ~20 mV drops of this line when I am transmitting.
I think this messes with the internal ADC, and gives faulty readings.

**What I've tried**

To prevent this I tried adding several capacitors, low ESR 100uF electrolytic capicitor, 100uF tantulum capacitors, and a 0.1uF ceramic capacitor. None seemed to have any significant effect.

**The question**

Should I use a different capacitor, or are there any other factors I should take into account? I tried looking for an external ADC that would be powered with its own LDO, but that would add a lot of complexity.

**Schematic**

This is my schematic, not 100% accurate, microphone also has a 2k bias from VCC:
[image]

Comment: A circuit diagram would be helpful.  Have you checked the bias voltage that goes to the microphone?  Noise there will get into your microphone signal.

Comment: @JRE Thanks for cleaning up my question. Unfortunately my circuit diagram is a bit of a mess, I will try to clean it up and post it. I have not checked the bias voltage, but all of my audio circuitry is powered with a separate LDO, a HT7333-A, to prevent noise.

Perhaps there is noise on the battery line, going into both the LDO's?

Comment: Do you just play a received packrt once it's received? If the data sent in those 1000 transmissions per second is not properly buffered digitally, a 1000Hz tone is quite expectable.

Comment: 20ms*50Hz is not "1000 transmissions per second"

Comment: How are the capacitors physically located near the ESP32?

Comment: Does the ESP32 have a VREF pin? (I don't actually know)

Comment: @SimSon No I don't immediately play the received packets, I do buffer them digitially.

Comment: @user253751 I never said 50 Hz, maybe I didn't explain it properly. I retrieve 20 ms of sound from a i2s DMA buffer, encode it, then send that sound packet 50 times, then I wait for the buffer to have 20 ms again and rinse and repeat. So I send each packet of 20 ms 50 times, giving 1000 Hz

Comment: @bart the buffer fills up 50 times per second, right? and you send each buffer 50 times? that's 2500 packets per second

Comment: @user253751 Caps are within 1 centimetre of ESP32, width wide tracks. Not sure about the VREF, never used something needing an external reference, maybe this: https://www.esp32.com/viewtopic.php?t=4354 ?

Comment: I still bet it has something to do with your sampling. 1000Hz is an uncommon frequency for noise because typical noise sources have either much lower frequencies (line noise, humming) or much higher frequencies (DCDC-converters etc). I would play with the packet size to see if the noise frequency correlates and/or make a FFT with manually concatenated packets.

Comment: @user253751 You are correct in that my math does not check out, I will rephrase the question

Comment: You might even miss some samples while you are transmitting if you are not reading the ADC during that time. 1000Hz is most likely not an incident!

Comment: @SimSon All ADC samples are written to a DMA buffer, which I "clean out" every 20 ms, so I am not missing samples. When I am not transmitting, I don't get the noise.

Comment: Sounds good, hmm... can you post a layoutor picture of your circuit?

Comment: @SimSon I've added a schematic, hopefully that helps

Comment: You can test by replacing the mic preamp with something that gives a constant DC voltage, and is insensitive to RF, like an AA battery. Aim for ADC mid-scale, make sure the ADC is not clipped. The ADC should acquire a constant DC level. Do you get noise, or no noise?

Comment: @bobflux Thank you for your troubleshooting suggestion! I now think that a 20 mV ripple would be too low to generate the noise anyway, I will definitely give your suggestion a try!

Comment: The reason I suggested that is: you want to know whether it's the mic preamp picking up the noise from the supply (in this case you need a mic preamp with higher PSRR) or the ADC itself (in this case you need a better ADC or a better reference voltage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out. I assumed that the 5V line (actually battery, so more like 3.7V), was not susceptible to noise and was 100% consistent. It was not. Apperently there was something like 100mV noise when transmitting, which after a HT7333-A LDO was 10mV noise on my audio power line. Due to my terrible microphone preamp (still don't really know why it even works), this was amplified to 300mV noise which my ESP32 DAC happily picked up.

This was all solved by using the more modern RT9080-33GJ5 which apperently has a *way* better PSRR, thus giving almost no noise on my audio power line.
Thanks @bobflux you were right on the money with your guess.